# how to change image of jquery slider plugin

Tags: plugin-development, images, slideshow

I want to put the "swiper slider" in my front page. I can set this plugin work with html, js, css.
But, I wonder how to change images of this slider in admin.
when I use jquery plugin, I want to change image of slide in admin area.
Can you give me some tips to change images in admin that is tagged  in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to make the slider dynamic.

If you use the Gutenberg editor, you can add new style to the Gallery like this:

```php
register_block_style( 'core/gallery', [
  'name'  => 'swiper',
  'label' => __( 'Swiper Slider' ),
] );
```

Then create gallery and choose the Swiper style. It will add an extra class `is-style-swiper` to the gallery. Target that with CSS and JS.

If you use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields), then it's even easier to change the HTML markup to fit whatever Swiper needs.